# ASP.NET 5.0 Session State and Azure cache

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to use the ASP.NET 5.0 Session State middleware and i want to use it with Azure cache as the session store? 
Can someone point out samples to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET 5 the session state system requires an implementation of `IDistributedCache` to be available in the service provider (via dependency injection). So, the session-state system should be usable as-is; you'll just need a Redis implementation of `IDistributedCache`.

The ASP.NET 5 [Caching repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching) has a sample [Redis distributed cache provider](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis) that uses [Redis](http://redis.io/) as the backing store.

There is also an accompanying [sample app](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples/RedisCacheSample) that shows direct usage of the distributed cache provider.

Plugging in Azure Cache (which is based on Redis) is left as an exercise to the reader (that's you!).

Comment: Thanks Eilon, that worked. So will i have to use Redis cache? can i use the Azure Managed cache service?

Comment: It's conceivable that you could use the Azure Managed Cache, but I think the Azure Redis Cache is newer and might be more appropriate for this scenario, especially because there's already a sample of how to use Redis with ASP.NET 5.

Comment: The Azure Cache team recommends Redis for all new developments.  See this article for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn766201.aspx